# ActionBar implementation throws an exception

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am implementing ActionBar for Android. I am having difficulties with my Java code. When I run my app Eclipse throws me an error in my code:

```
package com.example.android.rssfeed;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class RssfeedActivity extends Activity implements
    MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener { // this is the place where it shows me an error

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssfeed);
  }

  //NEW
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
  }

  //NEW
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Action refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
      break;
    case R.id.action_settings:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Action Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }

    return true;
  }


}
```

I left a comment where the error is.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity needs to override the methods in of the `MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener` interface, otherwise it shows a compiler error.